# adding object to a dictionary get a different value than expected

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have some strange behavior, working on it for 5 days and cant seems to find the problem yet. I don't know whether it's my stupid mistakes or I'm using a bad approach so such things happened. But I assumed that the List is the problem but I'm not sure.

> I'm using a **List** of a class named **Item** as models of my json. I
>   think there's no problem on the List of Item, because I have checked
>   all of the **Item** on the **List**, and it has the same value just like on the json.

My approach is using a list that accessed by a key on every item, so that I'm using a Dictionary. **But something strange goes like this**:

> **Item** added to **dictionary** goes looped **(adding the same key and value)** after item number 30, but when I checked it using breakpoints, var item in items **has the right value as I expected**. But when it is **added to the dictionary**, the item added to it(dictionary) is not the item in local variable foreach statement just added before

This is the Model from JSON

```
class Item
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public double CF { get; set; }
}
```

here is the code that has some strange behavior that I cant seemed to find out:

```
modelItems = new Dictionary<string, factItem>();
itemsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                item.CF = 0;
                if (!item.Question.Equals(""))
                {
                    factItem f = new factItem(item.Key, item.Description, item.Question);
                    f.CF = 0;
                    modelItems.Add(item.Key, f);
                }
                itemsDictionary.Add(item.Key, item);
            }
```

The factItem inherit the Item Class, and has the same problem too.

Here is the screenshot. I'm using breakpoint and iterate it right before the strange behavior happened and when the strange behavior begin:

> [Sorry, I dont have enough reputation so I uploaded the picture](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6bYTR1cWl3_flhwVS1QSTh2emU1M3VIaVNOb3hlNGlBVy1tZzlnQWlMYlcyVUtHZ28zY2s&usp=sharing)

---

I already using a different approach for translating list into dictionary, using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue> = list.ToDictionary(funcForKey, funcForValue)` but still facing the same problem.

**I would really appreciate to everybody that responded to my question**

Comment: You haven't explained clearly what the actual problem is.  It appears it may be that the items are not ordered, but you haven't specifed.  If that is indeed the case, it actually shouldn't matter because one of the primary reasons to use a dictionary is the speed of a lookup based on key, so sorting doesn't really matter anyway.  And if you had to sort them, you can just use linq's OrderBy or [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The problem seems to be like a glitch in Visual Studio inspecting vars while debugging, if you check [the third screenshot](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/BpX7lKoEiujHP33vJ6P3maGDa_YmUWYj-VLnee2fU3ZBbkmQXg_3XxtdZ_CXRuXgYkxhwQ=w1342-h585): Key in the dictionary for that entry is "X016", while the key field for that item is "X030".

Comment: Agree it's likely some sort of Visual Studio bug in displaying the data.  To check that the dictionary is actually good, add the following assert: `Debug.Assert(!itemsDictionary.Any(pair => pair.Key != pair.Value.Key));`.

Comment: Finally, I found that this is the Visual Studio bug, like @BlasSoriano said. Thanks guys. Maybe Soriano could post it as an answer and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of entries is important, then you should consider using `SortedDictionary` object instead of generic `Dictionary`; more details on implementation at MSDN online: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your respond sir, but the order of the list is not important here. I have edited the question to clear out what the problem is. The item inside the list is added to dictionary. On the next iteration, the added item to dictionary is not the actual item added before

Comment: Then you probably have to check your business logic and data sources. It's really hard to debug your code without knowing that specific implementation details. I would also recommend to re-format your question replacing those images with some readable text. Kind regards,